# Full Screen Toggle Button in Cross Media Manager Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using [CrossMediaManager](https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager) for video playback. Full Screen option is not available in the video playback controls list for Android. iOS plugin has maximize feature I want similar functionality in Android too and need a little bit of a guidance and jump start.

Thanks for your time, much appreciated. Have a great day!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: May not be possible: https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager/issues/571